# Fourier transform to find an harmonic function (Strauss)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I am trying to solve one of the problems of section 12.4 of the book "Partial Differential Equations" by Strauss. The problem says:

Use the Fourier transfor in the $x$ variable to find the harmonic function in the half plane ($y>0$) that satisfies the Neumann condition $u_y=h(x)$ on $y=0$.

So I did the fourier transform of the laplacian, but when I solve the new ODE I am missing one boundary condition. Is there any asymptotic condition that I should consider?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A reasonable condition might be that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|u(x,y)|^{2}dx \le M$ for some constant $M$ and all $y > 0$.

Comment: ??? I'd think if we're wondering about "conditions" we'd be looking for conditions on $h$ that make it all work. $h$ is given; $u$ is what we're looking for.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : There are probably several conditions required for a well-posed problem in this case. Working in $L^{2}$, I suppose you would want $h\in L^{2}$ and the vector map $y \mapsto u(\cdot,y)\in L^{2}$ to have one derivative in $y$ at $y=0$, which would be equivalent to $h,h' \in L^{2}$. Then you would probably want the bound I stated in the previous comment. Can you think of anything else?

Comment: @TrialAndError If your notation is supposed to be consistent with the OP seems to me you're shifted by one - you meant to say $h=f'$, where $f,f'\in L^2$. (???) (I for no reason was thinking about the analogous $L^1$ condition; the $L^2$ is probably better, easier to check. Too much time thinking about Fourier series, where the $L^1$ condition is weaker...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : Yes, I slipped gears on that. And ... $L^{1}$ can work, too ...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : Some boundedness condition on $u$ needs to imposed. For example $w(x,y)=e^{-(x^{2}-y^{2})/2}\cos(xy)$ is a solution of Laplace's equation for which $u_{y}(x,0)=0$ (I think that's right.) There needs to be boundedness in the variable $y$ such as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|u(x,y)|^{2}dx \le M$ for all $y > 0$.

Comment: @TrialAndError Some boundedness condition on $u$ needs to be imposed if we want to say something about uniqueness, yes. This is the first time uniqueness has come up here. If we're constructing a solution to prove existence, which is all that was asked for, we don't need to impose any such condition. Especially since if we construct the solution as a Poisson integral, as in my answer, conditions like the one you mention _follow_ from the construction.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : The point at which this discussion of non-uniqueness applies in in the question where the OP asks, "So I did the fourier transform of the laplacian, but when I solve the new ODE I am missing one boundary condition. Is there any asymptotic condition that I should consider?" This issue of non-uniqueness surfaces directly in that discussion because you cannot rule out the $e^{y|\xi|}$ in all cases, right? It depends on the initial condition. So, an asymptotic of some kind is needed in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

There is some ambiguity in this problem, just as you pointed out in your question. If you start with the Fourier transform of your equation in $x$, which is given by
$$
                \hat{u}(s,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-isx}u(x,y)dx,
$$
then the equation in $y$ is informally
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial y^{2}}\hat{u}(s,y)
   & =-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-isx}\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}dx \\
   & = -(is)^{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-isx}u(x,y)dx.
\end{align}
This gives rise to the equation
$$
           \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial y^{2}}\hat{u}(s,y)-s^{2}\hat{u}(s,y)=0.
$$
You were correct that there are two solutions
$$
           \hat{u}(s,y) = A(s)e^{y|s|}+B(s)e^{-y|s|}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
           \hat{u}(s,0) = A(s)+B(s),\\
           \hat{u}_{y}(s,0) = |s|A(s)-|s|B(s)=\hat{h}(s).
$$
Because of the exponent, it is tempting to rule out a non-zero $A$, but you can't do that in general. For example, the following is a solution of Laplace's equation:
$$
             u(x,y) = e^{-(x^{2}-y^{2})/2}\cos(xy) = \Re e^{-(x+iy)^{2}/2}
$$
Furthermore, $u_{y}(x,0)=0$. And this is okay because $A(s)$ in this case is the Fourier transform of a Gaussian, which tempers $e^{y|s|}$ because $A(s) = Ce^{-s^{2}}$, which leaves $e^{y|s|-s^{2}}$ absolutely integrable and square integrable in the variable $s$.

If you require $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|u(x,y)|^{2}dx \le M$ for some $M$ and all $y$, then you can rule out such problems. Regardless, you are correct that there is a missing piece that cannot be ignored without some further asymptotic or condition in $y$.

Comment: Yes, if that's what we're doing then you have a point about uniqueness. Although you really don't need to say anything about uniqueness or boundedness of norms; we're looking for a solution and we're free to simply _try_ setting $A=0$ because it looks like a good idea.

Comment: Ron's insistence that I'm _lying_ about this notwithstanding, I didn't realize that's what the OP was doing. Because she said she took the FT of the Laplacian, and there's no FT of any Laplacians anywhere in sight in your post. (After you decide $A=0$, you take your FT and put it into the inversion formula and you get the formula at the _start_ of my post. What you did is not the only way to  get there. If we assume that $u$ is the Poisson integral of something that formula follows.)

Comment: I was trying to address the concern of the OP : "So I did the fourier transform of the laplacian, but when I solve the new ODE I am missing one boundary condition. Is there any asymptotic condition that I should consider?" A natural asymptotic condition is $\int |u(x,y)|^{2}dx \le M$ for all $y > 0$; that should be both necessary and sufficient for guaranteeing that $A\equiv 0$ (at least in  L2), which makes the condition rather interesting as well. But the main thing is that this addresses the missing condition in solving the ODE through an asymptotic behavior, as asked by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: All the formulas in this post are wrong. They all need $\pi$'s inserted in various places. (Partly I'm lazy. Partly we want to leave something for you to do. Mainly the problem is that every book uses a different definition of the Fourier transform, with the $\pi$'s in different places - no way I could possibly give FT formulas that will be valid with the FT in your book...)

Anyway, here's a basic fact about Poisson integrals versus the Fourier transform: If $f$ is a nice function on $\Bbb R$ (Lebesgue integrable is nice enough) and $$u(x,y)=\int e^{-y|\xi|}e^{ix\xi}\hat f(\xi)\,d\xi$$then $u$ is harmonic in the upper half plane and tends to $f$ (in various sense, depending on how nice $f$ is) on the boundary. Now it appears that 
$$u_y(x,y)=-\int e^{-y|\xi|}e^{ix\xi}|\xi|\hat f(\xi)\,d\xi.$$
So it would seem that you want $$\hat h(\xi)=-|\xi|\hat f(\xi).$$
So $f$ should be the inverse transform of $-\hat h(\xi)/|\xi|$.

Comment: Not to knock you because your answer is more or less correct.  But the excuse of leaving it to the OP to do work results in a shabbily communicated result.  Remember, the OP is asking about an inherent boundary condition - you do point out the correct answer, but you should really provide the missing link.  Also, as one who has taught FT's to young'uns...those $\pi$'s are important details!  Better to pick a scheme and stick with it.  (The OP apparently could not be bothered with choosing one, so you might as well.)

Comment: @RonGordon I don't quite get your point. Giving a hint and leaving details to the OP seems to me to be perfectly standard around here; why is the question of where the $\pi$'s go an exception?

Comment: For one, you never really answered the OP's question - note (s)he didn't seek the solution but was merely asking about the asymptotic condition.  You could have just stated that and defined a nice FT, $\pi$'s and all.  No hint required here.  Also, stating up front what what you are saying is "wrong" only makes me want to look at your answer like I want to look at a car accident.

Comment: @RonGordon Seems to me you're changing the subject - I don't see how that's an answer to my question. (Regarding what you said, instead of the question of whether it answers my question: True, I didn't actually answer the question. I didn't quite understand the question; in any case it seemed likely to me that "missing one boundary condition" wasn't the actual problem with what the OP had done (yes, that's a guess).)

Comment: Look, I'm not trying to mess you up, just improve the content.  (I could have just put in a better answer, but why bother when you're almost there?)  What is the missing BC?  I am sure you understand that much.

Comment: Trying to improve content is good. When you make a suggestion, I ask a question about your suggestion, and you simply don't answer my question I don't see how that's all that constructive. Of course you know that I understand things that I've explicitly stated I don't understand, so I imagine there are other things you see that I don't.

Comment: @RonGordon I take back what I said about just guessing (in my comment a minute ago - forgot the @Ron). The OP said she took the FT of the Laplacian. This would seem to indicate to me that she was going about the whole thing wrong, not just missing a boundary condition.

Comment: I disagree - I just think that the OP was being quite lazy.  As I noted, no notational definitions, nothing to bring the general public onto the same planet (s)he is.  But I think we can understand what taking the FT of the Laplacian means.  I think, despite the laziness, it is quite clear what (s)he is asking.

Comment: @RonGordon I didn't say I didn't understand what taking the FT of the Laplacian means. Taking the FT of the Laplacian seems totally irrelevant here - what comes up is the FT of the boundary function.

Comment: @RonGordon : Why don't you post solution as you think it should be?